# Counter example that a convex set is not necessarily an interval or ray .

Tags: general-topology, analysis, examples-counterexamples

The example I am trying to frame is like this :

> I am considering the dictionary order on $\mathbb{R}^2$ , now I know that the set $S=\{x^2+y^2<1\}$ is a convex set(I am confused that it is with respect to which order).It doesn't look like that $S$ is an interval or ray.

I need some help to frame this question properly to give an example.

Comment: As far as I know convexity is not connected with orders. It is a property of subsets in vector spaces.

Comment: @MaximNikitin there exists (linear) convex and (order) convex, as well as metric convex and a common theory for all of these, even (convexity spaces).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I am reading topology for the first time and the confusion that I have is that , does the order decide what type of interval a topological space has ?What is order convex?

Comment: As you said, the dictionary order on $\Bbb R^2$ is the order you must use to judge whether a set is $S$ order convex, which means by definition: $\forall x,y \in S \forall z \in X: x < z < y \to z \in S$, so $S$ is closed under the relation of being inbetween.

Comment: How do the intervals in $R^2$ look like in dictionary order?

Comment: I think here $S$ is not convex in $\mathbb{R}^2$ wrt. the dictionary order. Because If we have two points in $S$ such that, $(a,b)$ (First quadrant) and $(-a,b)$ (Second quadrant), then there exist a point $(-a,nb)\notin S$ but $\in \mathbb{R}^2$ ($n\in \mathbb{N}$, sufficiently large), such that, $(-a,b)<(-a,nb)<(a,b)$, so, $(-a,nb)\in$ the interval $((-a,b),(a,b))$ but not in $S$. So, I think $S$ is not convex from the definition of convexity of ordered topological space.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I don't think that $S$ is order convex here. Shankhadeep has already given an argument. As a concrete example, $(-1/2, 0)$ and $(1/2, 0)$ are in $S$ but the element $(0, 2)$ in between them, is not. I think OP's confusion stems from different usages of "convex".

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I think so too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your recent posts, I think the multiple usages of "convex" in different contexts is causing confusion. Hopefully the following sheds some light.

---

**Definition 1.** (Convex, in the context of vector spaces)
A subset $S \subset \Bbb R^n$ is said to be *convex* if for all $x, y \in S$ and $t \in [0, 1]$, it is the case that $tx + (1 - t)y \in S$.

(In general, you can replace $\Bbb R^n$ with any $\Bbb R$-vector space $V$, if you know what those are.)

The above definition says that given two points in $S$, the line segment joining the two points is contained in $S$.

---

**Definition 2.** (Convex, as in Munkres)
Let $L$ be a simply ordered set. $S \subset L$ is *convex in $L$* if given any $a, b \in S$ and $c \in L$ with $a < c < b$, it is the case that $c \in S$.

In other words, given two points in $S$ and any point of $L$ in between them, that point must actually be in $S$. (Note that this depends on your bigger set $L$.)

The above is actually sometimes the definition of an *interval*. But Munkres defines that in another manner.

---

Now, the two definitions above coincide for the case that $L = \Bbb R$ but for $\Bbb R^n$ (with $n > 1$), it does not. Firstly, to apply the second definition to $\Bbb R^n$, we would need an order on it. The usual choice would be the dictionary order but the definitions of convex won't coincide.

The $S$ described in your post is an example of this. (Do you see how?)

---

**Definition 3.** (Interval, as in Munkres)
Let $L$ be a simply ordered set. An *interval* is a set which is of one of the following forms:

1. $(a, b)$,
2. $[a, b)$,
3. $(a, b]$,
4. $[a, b]$,

for some $a, b \in L$.

The definitions of those sets are the usual one.

---

It is easy to see that all intervals are convex but the converse is not true.

Consider the simply ordered set $L = \Bbb Q$ in the usual order and the subset $$S = \{x \in \Bbb Q : x^2 < 2\} \subset \Bbb Q.$$
Then, $S$ is convex (in $\Bbb Q$!) but it not of the above four forms.

Munkres also defines what a ray is. I leave it to you to verify that $S$ is not a ray either.

---

**Moral.** The same words have different meaning in different parts of math and you should be careful in seeing what they are defined as.